# Text and Image in Table HTML /CSS

Tags: css, html-table

Does anybody know how to get above and below the image, text in the table?
Now I have this:

[image]

This is my code:

[image: Code]

Comment: You cab use the **figcaption** tag, or see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13038306/arrange-caption-over-an-image) answer.

Comment: if text and img are in the same cell, then set display:block to img .screenshots are useless

Comment: Why did you post a screenshot of your code? Post the code itself.

Answer (score 3):

Simply add the text before and after the `<img>`tags and add a linebreak.

You also have two closing `</td>` element after each image. Please see my code below for proper code.

The `<br />` code you see stands for a line-break. It starts a new line. If you remove those codes the text and images would be next to eachother instead of below eachother.

Example:

```css
/* ignore the CSS, it's mainly for looks */

table {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

td {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Text<br /><img src="image.jpg" /><br />Text</td>
    <td>Text<br /><img src="image.jpg" /><br />Text</td>
    <td>Text<br /><img src="image.jpg" /><br />Text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Text<br /><img src="image.jpg" /><br />Text</td>
    <td>Text<br /><img src="image.jpg" /><br />Text</td>
    <td>Text<br /><img src="image.jpg" /><br />Text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `<br />` is not the answer., just a hack

Comment: Ah hack? He simply wants to put text above and below an image. This should be fine for someone that is only beginning to learn HTML. I debated about using a `<p>` element (because I did not want to go into CSS for now) but this seemed to be easier for him to understand.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options. If you want it all very nice and clean I recommend more rows like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>text above pic1</td>
        <td>text above pic2</td>
        <td>text above pic3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>pic1</td>
        <td>pic2</td>
        <td>pic3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>text below pic1</td>
        <td>text below pic2</td>
        <td>text below pic3</td>
    </tr>
    [...and so on...]
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add text before and after the img tag, and set "display:block" to the img tag. That solved the problem for me.